# Artifactory - Explicity clean up old snapshots

Tags: maven, artifactory

According to [docs](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Disk+Space+Usage#ManagingDiskSpaceUsage-LimitingtheNumberofSnapshots), we may setup *Max Unique Snapshots* to discard old snapshots of an artifact at each new deploy.

And as written:

> Redundant snapshots are not deleted immediately Every 5 minutes,
>   Artifactory runs a background process that checks the value of Max
>   Unique Snapshots and deletes the oldest snapshots beyond that number.
>   For example, if you currently have 7 snapshots and set Max Unique
>   Snapshots to 5 then next time the background process runs, it will
>   delete the 2 oldest snapshots.

I have two questions:

- Is that '5 minutes scheduler' configurable? It seems not working properly (tested in version 2.6.4).
- What about any troubles with performance/slowing down server if I have an Artifactory with 3 years+ with around 250gb? Will that job work normally and as expected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Artifactory not deleting Unique Snapshots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905747/artifactory-not-deleting-unique-snapshots)

Answer (score 2):

Artifactory does not delete snapshots just because you decreased value *Max Unique Snapshots*. You need to push another snapshot to trigger cleanup process for given group+artifact+version.

In other words you need to delete manually old snapshots. Setting will be applied only for newly uploaded snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

The 5 minutes period is not configurable, but should just work. What didn't work for you? 
Regarding performance issues - we really recommend upgrading to Artifactory 3. It shows 10 to 100 times performance improvements over version 2.

Comment: the problem is that I have N projects with 10+ snapshots each one. when I set 'max unique snapshots' to 2, when I do next artifact deploy, the folder is clean to 2 snapshots just for that project that was deployed, all others still with 10+ files